# dojo AMD module methods in chrome chrome/firebug

Tags: dojo, firebug, google-chrome-devtools, amd

Before AMD, we could use methods directly in chrome/firebug command line like:`dojo.byId()` or `dijit.byId()` etc.

But in AMD form, how we will get methods available in a module in command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the complete syntax on one line like this:

```
require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom) { console.log(dom.byId("search")); });
```

and for `dijit.byId()`:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) { console.log(registry.byId("search")); });
```

Comment: thanks Dimitri !! yes, but how we will come to know other registry properties/methods like byId ?

Comment: It's usually well documented. If you look for dojo.byId you will get: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/byId.html if you look for dijit.byId you will get: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/byId.html. As you can see they both say it's deprecated and they give you the module that is the replacement.

Comment: And if you want to know the other methods/functions you can use the API documentation, for example: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dijit/registry

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the modules in the global space by putting the following snippet in your html :

```
<script type="dojo/require">
    dom : "dojo/dom",
    registry : "dijit/registry"
</script>
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#declarative-require

That way, you can use the modules directly in the chrome console. e.g. :

```
registry.byId("someId")
```

Comment: I think I may add something like this to all my pages in debug mode, sick of writing out full AMD syntax when I just want to see the source docs / run a quick test. Thanks!